# Android Importing Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I've been trying to add a facebook login/share option in my app for almost 3-4 days and I'm completely unable to do so, I keep getting errors in every step I make.

I have been following alot of tutorials, and here's one of them:
https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1855739941322466/?platform=android

I almost finished all the steps, but I see that I have an issue in the first step, can't import the SDK.

Here's my build.grade(Project: Facebookapp)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

      }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
      }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Just added the "mavenCentral()" and removed the comment lines.

And here's the build.grade(Module: App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hesham.facebookapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

But basically, the last compile line:

> compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

causes an error in the R, which I can't solve. This is a new project by the way, because the old project was a huge mess, so I'm not sure if I forgot to add something, but I believe the compile line is what was causing all the problems.
Hope if someone can help, thank you.

Edit; I've also tried

> compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'

as the one I have in my android project, and still an error in the R.

Answer (score 1):

In your project, open
your_app | Gradle Scripts | build.gradle **(Module:app)**

Add the Maven Central Repository to build.gradle **before dependencies**:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Add **compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'** to your build.gradle **(Module:app)** dependencies instead of **compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
}
```

Till version 4.22.1, I don't get any errors, but from 4.23.0 I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

- If you do the step by step, your problem will be solved. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/
- You should also use the latest version of a libraries(support,appcombat etc.)
- Another problem is that you have to sync the project with the solution of R

Comment: This is almost the same tutorial, and I followed this for a little bit. But still having the same problem in step 3, there's a problem with the compile 'sdk'

Comment: "Can't resolve symbol R". This occurs when I add the compile line for the facebook sdk.

Comment: -Click on Build->Clean Project and that will perform a gradle clean. File - İnvalidate Caches/Restart and Sync The project. I think it will be solved.

Comment: Doesn't work, and still unable to import it. There's something wrong with the compile line, because when I remove it, everything runs normally.

Comment: I had this same problem. There's more than one build.gradle. I was making changes to the wrong one. I had to make the suggested changes in myapplication>build.gradle